# Automatically setting a menu on location 'primary menu' on theme activation

Tags: wordpress, menu, themes, activation

Currently I'm making this menu:
(Functions.php)

```
$menuname = 'Top Menu';
$menu_exists = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menuname );

if( !$menu_exists){
$menu_id = wp_create_nav_menu($menuname);

wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id, 0, array(
    'menu-item-title' =>  __('Programme'),
    'menu-item-classes' => 'programme',
    'menu-item-url' => home_url( '/programme/' ), 
    'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));

wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id, 0, array(
    'menu-item-title' =>  __('Speakers'),
    'menu-item-classes' => 'speakers',
    'menu-item-url' => home_url( '/speakers/' ), 
    'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));
}
```

When I activate my theme, what I'm looking to do is:
[image: Activating]
<sub>(source: [cubeupload.com](https://i.cubeupload.com/KmOErr.png))</sub>

Selecting the 'Primary Menu' box automatically so when I start this theme I create a menu and make it the primary menu.

How does one do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set the `theme_location` of the menu programmatically with:

```
$locations = get_theme_mod('nav_menu_locations');
$locations['primary-menu'] = $term_id_of_menu;
set_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations', $locations );
```

Add this to your `functions.php`.

Comment: Ah man no, this changes the menu completely from the database.

Comment: I added an answer, that is based on this answer - which a bit more functionality here: [Set navigation to be active for menu display location](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/403291/128304)